# 500 Internal Server Error /commerceops/CleanEnvironment()

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, habitathome

I am trying to setup HabitatHome.Commerce on Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 update 2. 
On Postman the Post for GetToken **SitecoreIdentityserver** is working fine and so as I can see when I run the "**deploy-commerce-engine.ps1**" where as the **Authoring** https://localhost:5000/commerceops/CleanEnvironment() gives a *500 internal server error* on Postman and *Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel* on deployment script.

The Thumbprint on the *authoring,ops,shops* and *minion* config.json are pointing to my *enigineconnect* certificate and same mentioned in "*deploy-commerce-engine.ps1*".

localhost:5000 is CommerceAuthoring hostname.

The parameters for the "*deploy-commerce-engine.ps1*" as below:

> [string]$siteName = "sxp9u2.sc",
>       [string]$engineHostName = "localhost",
>       [string]$identityServerHost = "localhost:5050",   [switch]$Initialize,
>       [switch]$Bootstrap,
>       [switch]$SkipPublish,
>       [string]$webRoot = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot",
>       [string[]] $engines = @("Authoring", "Minions", "Ops", "Shops"),  [string]$BizFxPathName = "SitecoreBizFx",
>       [string]$IdentityServerPathName = "SitecoreIdentityServer",
>       [string]$engineSuffix = "Sc9",
>       [string]$CommerceOpsPort = "5000",
>       [string]$adminUser = "admin",
>       [string]$adminPassword = "b",     [string]$certificateName = "sxp9u2.sc.engineconnect",
>       [string]$publishFolder = (Join-Path $PWD "publishTemp")

Reference: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce

The error in script and postman are as below
[image]

[image]

Not sure what went wrong, Do anyone have any clue on this?

Comment: Can you post here log entries? Have you disabled antiforgery? Have you disabled SSL certificate validation in Postman? See my blog post here -> http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/25/setting-up-development-environment-with-postman-and-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9

Comment: can you verify if your site is secured?

Comment: @PeterProchazka yes before getting into HabiitatHome.Commerce I did the setup for the Postman and I did followed your post to do so. Thanks for the nice blog you wrote on this.

Comment: @VladIobagiu No when I browse sitecore https://sxp9u2.sc/sitecore/ I see it as not secure. Do I need to secure it and if yes what is the best way to do so?

Comment: what about the authoring server?

Comment: Same goes for all. SitecoreIdentityServer and all other website assigned by default with Sitecore commerce services SSL certificate(localhost) after installation of Sitecore Commerce.

Comment: Any clue on what is going wrong? I am still trying to fix this?